# What is the standard practice of writing test cases in spring MVC application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng, integration-testing

We are developing new Spring MVC application in which we have DAO and service layer. which layer should i write test cases in junit or testNG ?. What is the standard practice for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always better to write cases in controller layer.
If the test case execution happens in all the layer(from controller to DAO/DB) then the coverage will more(more than 90%). 
If you are using **Mockito** then you can mock the last layer(dao or any other layer), because sometimes DB operation are not suitable for test case.

If you are fine with interact with DB then you will get better coverage than mocking DAO.

**NOTE:** Try To cover most of the layer & functionality while writing test case.

Comment: can you recommand any method /tools or standard practice for integration testing. for testing Rest layer,service later and DAO layer

Comment: Dont write test case for all layers, write for Rest layer, then rest will call service & then DAO, in this way in this way you can cover all layer, if you are not able to set value of any object during test case execution then mock that object/method using Mockito . you can refer any Mockito  tutorial online

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing general (no corner cases) integration tests using junit and MockMvc for your endpoints, and unit tests using junit and Mockito for testing specific business cases in your service classes. In your unit tests you could then test all the possible scenarios and corner cases. Unit tests are better for this as they are smaller and easier to maintain, while integration tests make sure that your API is working correctly on a general level.

Comment: but when i am writing unittest for service layer , i have to use DAO layer with it. so whay if there is any fault with DAO layer.  for example : In CRUD Scenario i have to check whether record is inserted or not. In this case , should i use Dao layer method or write query directly in test case ?

Comment: For operations involving the database, you need integration tests if you really need to test some specific SQL query. So these tests are going to actually connect to your DB and perform some CRUD operation and then you can assert the results.

Comment: No I dont want to test database queries , I just want to test Service Layer but my service layer has dependency on DAO layer which could be faulty so even if my service layer is working correctly my test will fail